Open product detail in a new tab with right-click option

I'm trying to implement a card component in Angular that shows product
information. When I right-click on a card, I want to see the option to
open the detail page in a new tab. However, currently, when I open it
in a new tab, it just goes to the home page (/) instead of the detail
page.strong text

<div *ngIf="!error && !isEmpty" class="flex flex-wrap items-stretch w-full h-full justify-center lg:justify-start gap-4">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of allProductsArray">
    <div class="relative flex-none w-[320px] h-auto p-2 shadow-lg rounded-md">
      <div class="relative mt-4 overflow-hidden w-full aspect-square h-[320px] flex justify-center items-center">
        <img [src]="item.image" loading="lazy" alt="ui/ux review check"
             class="w-full h-full object-contain cursor-pointer"
             (click)="item.type === 'product' ? showDetail(item.product_id) : showKitDetail(item.product_id)">
        <!-- Discount Sticker -->
        <div *ngIf="item.discount > 0" class="absolute top-0 right-0 bg-red text-white text-xs font-bold px-2 py-1 rounded-bl-md z-10">
          -{{ item.discount }}%
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-6 flex flex-col gap-4">
        <div class="block">
          <div class="flex justify-between gap-2">
            <h5 class="text-xl font-medium leading-snug text-blue-gray-900 cursor-pointer"
                (click)="item.type === 'product' ? showDetail(item.product_id) : showKitDetail(item.product_id)">
              {{ getProductName(item) }}
            </h5>
            <div class="px-1 cursor-pointer" (click)="addWishList(item.product_id, item.type)">
              <!-- SVG icon here -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3 w-full">
            <p *ngIf="item.price === item.new_price">{{ 'price' | translate }} {{ item.price }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="item.price !== item.new_price">
              {{ 'price' | translate }} <span class="line-through decoration-red decoration-2 px-2">{{ item.price }}</span> {{ item.new_price }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
//
showDetail(id: any) {
  console.log(id);
  this.service.productDetail_id = id;
  localStorage.setItem('productId', this.service.productDetail_id);
  this.router.navigate(['/detail']);
}


What I Want to Achieve:
When I right-click on a product card, I want to open the detail page
in a new tab. I’ve set up the route to navigate to /detail, but it’s
not working when opening in a new tab. Instead, it defaults to the
homepage (/).

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'detail', component: DetailComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


Please paste entire router file, I didn't see the route for home page. don't omit any code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use window.open(your_url, "_blank") in your ts file.
Alternatively, you can use < a > tag with target="_blank" to open the link in new window.
If still it is not working then need to check with the routing file as @zdd suggested
